# How do I setup my gear to pick up folks wifi 200m away?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, signal-strength

I have a TP Link WR840N and a 5Ghz High gain antenna. I got it from student friends of mine. I have little to no PC skills, but my friends said this would help put me on the right path. I have a Lenovo Ideapad. My folks wifi is a huawei looks like a mini hifi? Anyway folks say no problem if I can receive the signal. But, I dont know if this will work or even how to start setting it up. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You don’t; 5 GHz doesn’t have a 200 meter range (even with a high gain antenna)

Comment: Wifi also needs both ends to be high gain in order to function, because wifi is a 2-way conversation.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Long distance wifi requires that BOTH devices be designed to communicate over the distance. You can't just use a high gain on one end, because wifi is a 2-way conversation.

Comment: Sometimes it does... Can't say how it works, though I assume it's because "high gain" also makes it more sensitive, and not merely more powerful. For example, we have a pair of directional 5 GHz bridges on buildings, and occassionally I've been able to connect to one of them with my regular smartphone from ~300 m & a few buildings away – not great speed, but I could actually browse the web through it at this distance. I've also read about people using Yagi antennas to "borrow" someone's unprotected Wi-Fi (i.e. connecting to a completely standard office AP) from _kilometers_ away.

Comment: Gain is the measurement of sensitivity, not power. A "high gain" antenna is one that is designed to capture low power, highly disbursed signals from a weak and/or distant transmitter. It would need to be coupled with a high power and/or very directional transmission antenna in order to send back to the receiver. Other major factors are together called "propagation" which are thing like weather, atmospheric conditions, physical barriers, that also impact. Good circumstances can result in odd events such as what you describe. You don't bet on those though.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.